# Scrolling to the top of a multi-select

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I'm looking for a way where, when a user selects an option in a multi-select and submits it(AJAX), the multi-select should scroll to the top showing the first option (including the optgroup label).

Here is the current code that I have

```
$('selectId').selectedIndex = 0;
$('selectId').selectedIndex = -1;
```

This does scroll to the first item in the select box but the optgroup label is not visible, since the scroll is just below the optgroup label and on the first option.

Any help on how to get the optgroup label visible would be helpful.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sfHtF/1/

Scroll all the way down, click on 'GoTop', it goes to "one" but doesn't show the optgroup label.

Comment: this differs cross-browser. in FF, it is visible. scrollTo should work, add `autocomplete="off"` to stop anal browsers from persisting state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here since I have found a solution

```
$('selectId').selectedIndex = -1; //de-selects all options
$('selectId').scrollTo(0,0); //sets the scroll to right at the top
```

Working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/sfHtF/4/

Thanks everyone for looking into it.

Comment: that scroll didn't work for me (`$(...).scrollTo is not a function` - Chrome 65.0.3325.181), but this did:  `$('selectId').scrollTop(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is switch the order of the lines in the function.

So:

```
$('selectId').selectedIndex = -1;
$('selectId').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Switching the order selects the first item (which I do not want) and does not show the optgroup label as well. Apologies if my post was not clear, what I wanted was, to have 'Select one or many' to be visible when the scroll goes to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I know op wants jquery, but here is plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("selectId").scrollTo(0,0);
```